# primefaces watermark disappears after disabling and re enabling a text field using p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using p:ajax of primefaces in a p:selectOneRadio, to disable and re-enable form input text fields. these text fields have watermarks which disappear after disabling and they do not appear even after re-enabling them. I could not figure out the problem. please help. The code chunk where it appears is as bellow

```
<h:outputText 
   value="#{msg['elicense.contractorLicenseForm.personal.licenseApplied']}"/>
<p:selectOneRadio id="licenseApplied" 
                  value="#{contractorLicenseBean.licenseApplied}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="0"/>
    <p:ajax update="licensePersonName, relationshipPersonName" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
<h:outputText value="When it is yes, it should skip to supervisor details"/>

<h:outputText 
   value="#{msg['elicense.contractorLicenseForm.personal.licensePersonName']} "/>
<p:inputText id="licensePersonName" 
             value="#{contractorLicenseBean.licensePersonName}" 
             required="true" 
             label="LicensePersonName" 
             disabled="#{contractorLicenseBean.licenseApplied=='1'}"/>
<p:watermark for="licensePersonName" 
             value="Person/firm/company on whose Favour License is Sought " 
             id="watermark2" />

<h:outputText 
   value="#{msg['elicense.contractorLicenseForm.personal.relationshipPersonName']} "/>
<p:inputText id="relationshipPersonName" 
             value="#{contractorLicenseBean.relationshipPersonName}" 
             required="true" 
             label="RelationshipPersonName" 
             disabled="#{contractorLicenseBean.licenseApplied=='1'}" />
<p:watermark for="relationshipPersonName" 
             value="Relationship of the Applicant " 
             id="watermark3" />
```

Comment: What primefaces version that you used?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `h:panelGroup` around your watermarked components and update that `h:panelGroup` instead of component.
Primefaces binds the watermark to component through JQuery. If you changes/update the component then events bound to that component will not work, that may be the reason for your Issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used primefaces 5.0, and I encountered as your problem. When I put the `p:inputText` into `p:panelGrid` and update the panelGrid. The problem was gone.

```
    <h:form>
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

        <p:selectOneRadio id="radio" value="#{watermarkView.radio}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="0"/>
            <p:ajax process="radio" update="panelGridInput" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <h:panelGrid id="panelGridInput" 
                     columns="3" cellpadding="5" 
                     style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <h:outputLabel value="Search: "/>
            <p:inputText id="keyword" 
                         value="#{watermarkView.keyword}"
                         required="true" 
                         label="Keyword"
                         disabled="#{watermarkView.radio eq '1'}"/>
            <p:watermark for="keyword" 
                         value="Search with a keyword" 
                         id="watermark" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Search: "/>
            <p:inputText id="keyword2" 
                         value="#{watermarkView.keyword2}"
                         required="true" 
                         label="Keyword"
                         disabled="#{watermarkView.radio eq '1'}"/>
            <p:watermark for="keyword2" 
                         value="Search with a keyword" 
                         id="watermark2" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton id="regular" 
                         actionListener="#{watermarkView.search}" 
                         value="Regular" 
                         ajax="false" /> 
        <p:commandButton id="ajax" 
                         actionListener="#{watermarkView.search}" 
                         value="Ajax" 
                         onclick="PrimeFaces.cleanWatermarks();" 
                         oncomplete="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();" 
                         update="messages" />
    </h:form>
```